# I can't draw more than one circle on an image

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I have a problem. I need to draw some circles on an image, but I don't know why, it only draws one circle. I put the code below to explain it better:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.previsualizacion);



    myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ctx = getApplicationContext();

    //Obtenemos la información del layout anterior y la asignamos al tamaño del paso
    data = getIntent();
    myBundle = data.getExtras();    

    presasX = myBundle.getStringArrayList("arrayPixelX");
    presasY = myBundle.getStringArrayList("arrayPixelY");
    colores = myBundle.getStringArrayList("arrayColores");      

    Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
    bitMap = bitMap.copy(bitMap.getConfig(), true);     
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitMap);                 

    Paint paint = new Paint();                          
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    //paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);      

    myImage.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    //changed set image resource to set image background resource
    myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pared);

    for(int i = 0; i < presasX.size(); i++)
    {
        if(colores.get(i).equals("1"))
        {
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);    
        }
        else if(colores.get(i).equals("2"))
        {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);  
        }
        else if(colores.get(i).equals("3"))
        {
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);   
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(Float.parseFloat(presasX.get(i)) * myImage.getWidth() / 100, Float.parseFloat(presasY.get(i)) * myImage.getHeight() / 100, 3, paint);
    }

  //invalidate to update bitmap in imageview
    myImage.invalidate();
}
```

I have on some ArrayList the coords of the points I want to draw, also this coords are relative to an image, so I have to multiply that coords for the imagewidht and imageheight.

It only draws one green circle, but I need to draw (in that chase) five green points and four red points.

I put the arraylist info too:

presasX = [49.583333333333, 80.833333333333, 13.541666666667, 4.5833333333333, 77.708333333333, 49.583333333333, 4.5833333333333, 95.208333333333, 96.875]

presasY = [49.722222222222, 5, 22.5, 20.277777777778, 33.888888888889, 49.722222222222, 20.277777777778, 54.722222222222, 61.666666666667]

colores = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Float.parseFloat(presasX.get(i)) * myImage.getWidth()` - given that `presasX.get(0) == 49.583333333333`, this is going to be a really very large number, outside the bounds of the image.

Comment: I divide by 100, but it does the same. Any idea?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288768/draw-on-canvas-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

This is because layout has not inflated fully and therefore myImage.getWidth() and getHeight() are returning 0. So in effect the center of all your circles is the same (top left corner of the ImageView) and the next one is overwriting the previous one.

For actual width and height you can use ViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener or programmatically create the ImageView with required dimensions or create a custom view extending the standard ImageView and implement its [onDraw](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)() etc.